# Linking IF/OR statement

Tags: excel

I have a drop down list cell, I want to create a value in a different cell such that if X in Cell 1 then A in Cell 2 `OR` if Y in Cell 1 then B in Cell 2 otherwise perform a different function. I think something along the lines of:

`=IF(OR(A1="X", 1...`

just not sure where to go from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What yo are describing is a nested if not OR:

```
=IF(A1="X","A",IF(A1 = "Y","B","different function"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i tried that it didn't work, but works now, looks like i had a typo